# ASP.NET HttpUtility.HtmlEncode how to modify WhiteList Characters

Tags: asp.net

I have a list of characters like this :

WHITE LIST: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVQXYZ&,;"()@$%-_+."

I want write a function which encode all characters from a string except these characters.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to html encode a string of characters, except the set mentioned, even though some of those characters may require enconding (e.g. ampersand).  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Actually this is the user defined set of characters. user can add/remove characters from the list. and the system should have to encode all of those characters those are not in this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I think this is a really bad idea, but just for the challenge...

```
Public Function fnsHTMLEncodeExcept(pvsStringToEncode As String, pvsCharactersNotToEncode As String) As String
    Dim voEncodedString As New Text.StringBuilder

    For viPosition As Integer = 0 To (pvsStringToEncode.Length - 1)
        Dim vsChar As String = Mid(pvsStringToEncode, viPosition, 1)
        If InStr(pvsCharactersNotToEncode, vsChar) > 0 Then voEncodedString.Append(vsChar) Else voEncodedString.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(vsChar))
    Next
    Return voEncodedString.ToString
End Function
```

However, I have NO IDEA how you are going to HtmlDecode it ... I won't bother asking why you need this kind of function.

Comment: hmmm.. on second thought, it is still possible to HTMLDecode it with a little extra effort.

Comment: Actually I don't want to encode all special characters, because the database is shared with multiple applications and I don't want to force everyone to decode the data. HTMLDecode is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. I really like the guys who help others.

Comment: Welcome, but note that this function is (arguably --due to the InStr()) an O(n * n) operation, so it can be slow if you are running it (over a large text) and (running it many times consecutively).

Answer (score 1):

If you indeed are wanting to change the functionality of `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`, you will need to create your own `HttpEncoder`.

[HttpEncoder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.aspx) - The **Remarks** section explain how to setup your website to use your `HttpEncoder` by default in the `HttpUtility`, `HttpServerUtility`, and `HttpResponseHeader`.

**Edit**

In response to *"can I modify the whitelist characters in HttpUtility?"*

No.  Internally the implementation for the default `HttpEncoder` calls `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` which in turn calls `WebUtility.IndexOfHtmlEncodingChars`.  This method uses a set of hardcoded values and thus you cannot modify the whitelist characters.  You would need to write your own `HttpEncoder` class.

Comment: can I modify the whitelist characters in HttpUtility ?